# Phpseclib PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class

Tags: php, web, phpseclib

I followed the installation instructions. I created the folder and ran the composer. I got the lock file and the vendor directory. I placed the JSON, lock files, and vendor directory on the server (hosted by GoDaddy).

I created a simple PHP file with a decrypt function.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$ky = '2345678901234567890123456789012'; // 32 * 8 = 256 bit key
$iv = '2345678901234567890123456789012'; // 32 * 8 = 256 bit iv

function Decrypt($string_to_decrypt)
{
    global $ky;
    global $iv;
    
    $cipher = new Crypt_Rijndael(CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_MODE_CBC);
    $cipher->setBlockLength(256);
    $cipher->setKeyLength(256);
    $cipher->setKey($ky);
    $cipher->setIV($iv);

    $rtn= $cipher->decrypt($string_to_decrypt);
    error_log('decrypt = '. $rtn, 0);

    return($rtn);
}
```

I tried putting the following include in and it got further but then complained about the BlockCipher. I put another include in for that and got further. I know this is not the correct way. I would have thought the autoloader would have taken care of this.

```
include('/home/n28d5aun99s6/public_html/Working/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php');
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message you are facing

Comment: `$cipher = new Crypt_Rijndael(CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_MODE_CBC)` is what you'd do for phpseclib v1 but then you say it "_complained about the BlockCipher_". BlockCipher is a class in the 3.0 branch and the API for the 3.0 branch looks quite different. In 3.0 you'd do `$cipher = new Rijndael('cbc')`. Rijndael extends the BlockCipher class. There is no Crypt_Rijndael class and trying to instantiate a class that doesn't exist should give you a fatal "class not found" error. More information is needed. What version of phpseclib are you using? What is the _exact_ error that you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have proper reference to that class. It lives in `phpseclib3\Crypt` namespace but your code neither imports from there using  `use phpseclib3\Crypt\Rijndael` nor have FQN given in when referenced in `new`. Also the class name is `Rijndael` and not `Crypt_Rijndael` ([source](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php)) so you should first ensure your code is working locally before uploading it anywhere otherwise you will be wasting time debugging.

Also your hardcoded `include` solves nothing and should be removed.

Please [read the about namespaces in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) as you seem to have knowledge deficit on that matter.